# Using $\epsilon - \delta$ method prove that $\lim_{(x, y)\to (\frac{\pi}{2}, 0)}xy\sin(x + y) = 0$

Tags: limits, multivariable-calculus

Using $\epsilon - \delta$ method prove that, $$\lim_{(x, y)\to (\frac{\pi}{2}, 0)}xy\sin(x + y) = 0$$

Here's what I tried:
$$|xy\sin(x + y)| \le |xy| \le \frac{|x|^2 + |y|^2}{2}$$

But I can't proceed from here, how to bring the term $|x - \frac{\pi}{2}|$?

Comment: You should indicate what you tried first, otherwise you won't get much help here.

Comment: Your last inequality is correct but useless here, since $x \to \pi/2$. But you should simply estimate $|x|$ by a positive constant...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a one-line proof:
$$
|xy \sin (x+y)| \leq |x| |y| |\sin (x+y)| \leq \pi |y|
$$
provided that $|x-\frac{\pi}{2}| < \frac{\pi}{2}$. Now pick $\varepsilon>0$ and choose $\delta = \min \left\{ \frac{\varepsilon}{\pi}, \frac{\pi}{2}\right\}$, so that
$$
|xy \sin (x+y)| \leq |x| |y| |\sin (x+y)| \leq \pi |y| < \varepsilon
$$
provided that $|x-\pi/2|<\delta$ and $|y|<\delta$.

Comment: Can you show the conclusion of the proof in your answer by choosing suitable $\epsilon$ and $\delta$?